# Powershell Script to update a line in a text file based off a get-childitem recursive search

Tags: powershell

Have an ini file I need to update the contents of. There is a line within that contains the path to javaw.exe. As part of an automated build, the path changes as Java versions update.

Need to overwrite the current line with the output of $directory

Sample of $directory - C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.1.12-hotspot\bin\javaw.exe

This is what I have so far, but the file is not updated, no errors.

Tried hardcoding the full path in $find but no joy, it does need to be dynamic though as I don't want to maintain a static version number, any ideas?

```
$filename = 'javaw.exe'
$searchinfolder = 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium'
$directory = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchinfolder -Filter $filename -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}
$file = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse.ini'
$find = 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\'
(Get-Content $file.replace($find,$directory)) | Set-Content $file
```

Comment: [1]Since you filter on `javaw.exe`, this line `$directory = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchinfolder -Filter $filename -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}` will return (an array) of full path names to the **file**. [2] You are trying to find the rootfolder in the ini file and replace that with that full path(s). At best, this will combine into awkwark non-existing paths.

Comment: [3] The brackets in the last line are positioned wrong. Should be `(Get-Content $file -Raw).replace($find,$directory)` [4] Because you are tampering with an INI, better use a dedicated module for that like [PsIni](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/2.0.3)

Answer (score 0):

Theo got me on the right track.

Final code that did what I wanted

```
$filename = 'javaw.exe'
$searchinfolder = 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium'
$directory = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchinfolder -Filter $filename -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}
$file = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse.ini'
$find = (Get-Content -Path $file -TotalCount 2)[-1]
(Get-Content $file -raw).replace($find,$directory) | Set-Content $file
```